# How can I include a file using Eigen's plugin include?

Tags: c++, c++17, eigen

I am trying to extend Eigen's matrix classes to work with my own library's using their #define. Eigen is located in `/usr/local/include`. My project is in a separate folder. I followed the guide specified [in their documentation](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicCustomizing_Plugins.html).

Here is where I defined the relative paths for my extensions in a file called `SparseMatrix`.

```
#define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "src/Eigen_Extension/Matrix_Extension.hpp"
#define EIGEN_SPARSEMATRIX_PLUGIN "src/Eigen_Extension/Sparse_Matrix_Extension.hpp"

#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
```

When I try to compile with `g++ test.cpp` , I get the error

```
SparseMatrix:59:33: fatal error: src/Eigen_Extension/Matrix_Extension.hpp: No such file or directory
   59 | #define EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN "src/Eigen_Extension/Matrix_Extension.hpp"
      |                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

Despite the error showing my file, I know gcc is trying to include `src/Eigen_Extension/Matrix_Extension.hpp` in Eigen's .h file. This does compile if I use an absolute path.

My question boils down to: (preferably) without build systems or arguments. how can I make this work with a relative path?

I tried creating a convoluted define structure using _*FILE*_.

Matrix_Extension.hpp:

```
#include "../../SparseMatrix"

#ifdef EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN
// source code 
#else
#EIGEN_MATRIXBASE_PLUGIN __FILE__ //to get absolute path of extension file
#endif
```

SparseMatrix:

```
#include src/Eigen_Extension/Matrix_Extension.hpp

#include <Eigen/Core>
```

Unfortunately, this ran into issues with the my code not having Eigen included despite the define guards.

Comment: Did you try adding `-I .` to your build flags?

Comment: @chtz That is my current fix, though I'd like to have a programmatic way of including them.